# I cannot get rid of the internal browser scrollbar in IE 11 (using simplebar)

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, internet-explorer-11

I have been forced to move away from `perfect-scrollbar` and `ngx-perfect-scrollbar` due to severe performance problems when used together with angular 2 in IE11. I'm working on a big project and there are lots of components initialised at once. I had to do several, not pleasant, tricks in order to maintain page performance in the smooth and responsive zone (D3 charts are particulary sensitive to this).

Anyway, I selected [simplebar](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar) due to it's usage of the native scroll which has a significant benefit in solving those performance problems. However I still have one major issue. When I init an instance of the scrollbar I get both the simplebar and the browser native scrollbar at once. I managed to work around this issue using this snippet of CSS code:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { /* for Mac OS X support */
    width: 0;
}
```

However this does not work with internet explorer 11. I still see the scrollbar. This is a deal breaker for me. IE 11 is a must, the client uses it in the whole organisation. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. CSS styles seem just fine at first glance. If I disable `simplebar` I see no scrollbar at all.

Comment: try `-ms-overflow-style: none;` for that container to which to want add scroll

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it does the job :D You could post it as an answer so I can select as accepted.

Comment: Hey Adrian I have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try like this

```
   -ms-overflow-style: none;
```

It will help you to remove the addition scroll of IE